# What is a distribution in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\partial \Omega$ being $C^2$. Suppose $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\nu>0$. It is said in the *Navier-Stokes Equations* by Constantin and Foias (in the chapter about weak solutions of the Stokes Equations) that

> $\nu \Delta u+ f$ is a distribution in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$

where $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is defined as the continuous dual of $H^1(\Omega)$ and 
$$
H_0^1(\Omega):=\overline{C_c^\infty(\Omega)}^{\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}}.
$$

I can understand that $L:=\nu \Delta u+ f$ is a distribution since
$$
H_0^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)\subset L_{\textrm{loc}}^1(\Omega)
$$
and any function in $L_{\textrm{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ can be identified as a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), which is a function from $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ to $\mathbb{R}.$

Here is my **question**:

> What does "$L$ is in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$" mean?

Comment: Ok, I just saw your other question, where you explicitly state that your definition of $H^{-1}$ is *not* as the dual of $H^1_0$. But *if* $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is defined as the dual of $H^1_0(\Omega)$, then the statement "$L$ is in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$" should simply mean that $L$ is not only continuous on $C^{\infty}_0$ but on all of $H^1_0$. But I guess this was obvious, sorry